# Computing $n^{\text{th}}$ root of a positive integer to arbitrary precision using integer arithmetic

Tags: arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory, roots, integers

There are various questions on this forum that appear similar, but my question pertains to writing code that can compute the $n^{\text{th}}$ root of a number $a$ correct to $p$ decimal places, where the value of $p$ is limited by the machine representation (but is unbounded in principle). I've implemented a straight-forward algebraic approach in Python. Without loss of generality, let's say we wish to compute the square root of $2$ to $10$ decimal places.

This is equivalent to finding the root of the equation $P_0(x) = -2 + x^2 = 0$, using only integers. Using binary search, I find the largest integer $r_0$ such that $P_0(x=r_0) \leq 0$. Then $r_0$ comprises the whole number part of the answer. To find the first decimal place, we substitute the variable $x$ in $P_0$ with $r_0 + x/10$. We get the equation $P_1(x) = -2 + (r_0 + x/10)^2 = 0$. Again, using binary search, compute the largest integer $r_1$ (actually $0 \leq r_1 \leq 9$) such that $P_1(x=r_1) \leq 0$. And so on we go, each time substituting $x$ with $r_i + x/10$ to find the $(i+1)^\text{th}$ decimal place. The problem is, that the coefficients of the resulting quadratic equations $P_i$ explode. E.g.

$P_0(x) = -2 + x^2 = 0$, "root" $r_0 = 1$

$P_1(x) = -100 + 20x + x^2 = 0$, "root" $r_1 = 4$

$P_2(x) = -400 + 280x + x^2 = 0$, "root" $r_2 = 1$

$P_3(x) = -11900 + 2820x + x^2 = 0$, "root" $r_3 = 4$

$\ldots$

$P_{10}(x) = -105527215600 + 28284271240x + x^2 = 0$, "root" $r_{10} = 3$

Eventually, the coefficients would be too large to be represented on a computer (although my laptop running Anaconda 4.0.0 64-bit distribution has produced $\sqrt{2}$ to $10000$ decimal places w/o a problem).

My **question** is: Is there a way to *approximate* the coefficients for the quadratic equations, to keep them within certain bounds, and still continue to obtain subsequent digits correctly? In particular, is there a counter-example which shows that nothing but the exact coefficients would yield the correct results? Does it help to know that the "root" $r_i$ of each quadratic equation $P_i$, $i > 0$, lies between $0$ and $9$?

Comment: You'd be much better off implementing Newton's method.

Comment: For speed, yes. But my motivation was to avoid floating point errors, without the use of specialist libraries. Hence this method, which uses only integers.

Comment: Newton's method only uses rational arithmetic and so works with rational numbers, that is, with integers. The Newton step for $\sqrt2$ is $(p,q) \gets (p^2+2q^2, 2pq)$.

Comment: Ah, I was prematurely scared off by the need to compute the derivative term of an n-ary polynomial. I guess it isn't a hassle. I'll implement it and check whether a similar situation (bloated coefficients) occurs there too.

Comment: The coefficients will grow because the iteration is quadratic and if $p/q$ is reduced so is the next value. There is no way around this growth.

Comment: You may want to consider  continued fractions, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Continued_fraction_representation. The growth is slower (but so is the approximation). The iteration is $(p,q) \gets (p+2q,p+q)$, starting at $(1,1)$.

Comment: So, does it make any sense to ask the same question in the context of Newton's method (perhaps every method if I may extrapolate this behavior)? Is there a way to bound the coefficients without losing accuracy? Or, is there a counter example?

Comment: There is no way to bound the coefficients without losing accuracy because there are only finitely many fractions $p/q$ with $p,q  \le N$ and so the distance from $p/q$ to $\sqrt2$ cannot go to $0$.

Comment: No, I didn't mean accuracy of the final answer. I just meant, e.g. with respect to my method, the accuracy of computing the i'th decimal digit. The i'th must be between 0 and 9 so can I not use smaller (bounded) coefficients instead?

Comment: And btw, thanks a lot for your responses.